# Extracting svn information from Jira

Tags: php, api, svn, soap, jira

Is it possible to extract svn information (commits etc.) from Jira via its api (Soap, Rest). I have Jira Subversion plugin enabled and it shows information about commits, but I don't know how to extract this information calling the api methods.

Comment: the only way to extract such data is to parse the page... That's a pity

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question. I do not know for any API call and the [SubversionPlugin Documentation](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/SVN/Subversion+JIRA+plugin) doesn't suggest one. But you could always get direct access to a read-only copy of your JIRA instance's DB or query it using the API.

Your best options is to try posting a question on the [Atlassian answers site](https://answers.atlassian.com/) or better yet creating a [support request](https://support.atlassian.com).

The thing is that if there is no API currently, they could be developing one right now and Atlassian may connect you with the developers so that they can give you further information.
They may even provide you with some early-access solution. I know this because we've used this option at the company I currently work at, but with the Tempo plugin. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll try posting question to Atlassian. In documentation for plugin did'nt find any useful information about this almost :(

Comment: Anyway hope this helped somehow. Please do consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it did you any good.